# sqldf "LIKE %" operator

Tags: sql, sqldf

I'm trying to extract text data from a column in my df, but r kept giving me syntax error:

`covid <- sqldf("SELECT * FROM df1 WHERE Case LIKE '%covid%'")`

`Error: near "'%covid%'": syntax error`

Could anyone point out to me what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `case` is an ANSI SQL reserved word (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words). Try `select Case from df1` - what happens? Reserved word column names need to be delimited, like `"case"`.

Comment: Ah no wonder I've been struggling. I forgot the basics. Sorry was a newbie and you just solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: It would be best if that comment was composed as an answer and got accepted.

Answer (score 0):

`case` is an ANSI SQL reserved word (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words). Reserved word column names need to be delimited, like `"case"`. I.e. something like:

```
SELECT * FROM df1 WHERE "Case" LIKE '%covid%'
```